# Somar todos os registros anteriores a uma data específica - SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou querendo somar valores de várias linhas da minha tabela (somar valores de despesas) anteriores a uma data específica (por exemplo, somar todos os valores que são menores que a data 2015-26-06). Estou usando o seguinte código, mas ele não é funcional.

```
SELECT SUM (VALOR) FROM despesa 
  WHERE strftime('%Y-m%-d%', data) <= strftime('%Y-m%-d%', '2015-06-30')
  AND pago = 1 AND idusuario = 1
```

Alguém poderia me orientar nisso? Agradeço desde já.

Estrutura da tabela Despesa

[image: tabela despesa]

Comment: "mas ele não é funcional." o que quer dizer com isso?

Comment: que ele retorna-me nulo, ou seja, não soma nada, não é funcional.. @PauloHDSousa

Comment: ele é funcional, você que está passando o parâmetro de modo errado. basta converter a data corretamente. A base está populada?

Comment: está sim, eu copiei ela do emulador pra poder testar os comandos usando o  SQLite Browser, você teria alguma dica de conversão? @PauloHDSousa

Comment: @PauloHDSousa teria alguma forma de pesquisar sem o dia? só usar ano e mês?

Comment: Sim, existe uma forma.

Comment: e como seria? @PauloHDSousa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim

```
SELECT SUM (VALOR) FROM despesa WHERE data <= Datetime('2015-06-30 00:00:00') 
  AND pago = 1 AND idusuario = 1
```

Comment: Muito bom PauloHDSousa, não tinha conhecimento desse Datetime no sqlite, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O erro está aqui: `strftime('%Y-m%-d%', data)`

A função `strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)` só aceita `string` como segundo argumento e você está passando um `DATETIME`.

O correto é o seguinte: `data <= strftime('%Y-m%-d%', '2015-06-30')` conforme a [documentação](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Outra causa que pode retornar `null` é quando a consulta não retorna registros.